# Looking for a proof of a weird Combinatoric identity I came across

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, alternative-proof, independence

Earlier today I came up with a very complicated "proof" of the probability multiplication rule for two independent events. I used the quotation marks because I ended up obtaining a very complicated formula for the wanted probability, and only verified that it gave the right values for different parameters by using desmos. But, I don't know how to simplify the formula into the more basic form. In short, I want to show that

$$
\sum_{i=1}^R \frac{i}{N}\frac{\frac{N!}{i! (R-i)! (B-i)!(N+i-R-B)!}}{\binom{N}{R} \binom{N}{B}}= \frac{RB}{N^2}
$$

Where $R\le B$, And $R+B\le N$

does anyone have any idea of how to do this?

Comment: If you said you counted in two ways the same thing, then it *is* a proof.

Comment: I added the $\LaTeX$ formula: is it correct?

Comment: In that case, your identity would simply to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^R \frac{i}{N}\frac{\frac{N!}{i! (R-i)! (B-i)!(N+i-R-B)!}}{\binom{N}{R} \binom{N}{B}}= \frac{RB}{N^2}=\sum_{i=1}^R \frac{i}{\binom{N}{R} \binom{N}{B}(B-i)!(N+i-R-B)!}= \frac{RB}{N}.
$$
Are you sure about it?

Comment: @Nduccio yes, that is correct! Thanks, I am new to posting here.

Comment: @Nduccio I feel confident that it's correct. But, besides the reasoning I used to arrive at that formula, my justification is just that the two equations give the same values on desmos for arbitrary cases. Do you see an issue with that form that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

LHS can be simplified to: $$\sum_{i=1}^R\frac{i}N\frac{\binom{R}i\binom{N-R}{B-i}}{\binom{N}B}$$

Then to be explained is the equality:$$\sum_{i=1}^R\frac{i\binom{R}i\binom{N-R}{B-i}}{\binom{N}B}=\frac{RB}N$$

The LHS of this equality can be recognized as the expectation of the number of red balls that appear if $B$ balls are taken randomly and without replacement from an urn that contains exactly  $N$ balls of which exactly $R$  are red balls.

Note that the LHS is $\sum_{i=1}^Bip_i$ where $p_i$ denotes the probability that $i$ red balls are drawn.

This expectation can be found on a more elegant way using linearity of expectation and symmetry.

For $i=1,\dots,B$ let $X_i$ take value $1$ if at the $i$-th draw a red ball is chosen and let $X_i$ take value $0$ otherwise.

Then to be found is: $$\mathbb E(X_1+\dots+X_B)=B\times\mathbb EX_1=B\times\frac{R}{N}=\frac{RB}{N}$$

So this tells us that the equality is a true statement.

---

Maybe this does not answer your question and you are after some unraveling of the LHS that ends up in the RHS. In that case I feel a too strong reluctance to think about any answer.

Comment: drhab Good job!

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin {array}{}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^R \frac{i}{N}\frac{\frac{N!}{i! (R-i)! (B-i)!(N+i-R-B)!}}{\binom{N}{R} \binom{N}{B}}
&=\frac{1}{N\binom{N}{B}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^R i\binom{R}i\binom{N-R}{B-i}\\
&=\frac{R}{N\binom{N}{B}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^R\binom{R-1}{i-1}\binom{N-R}{B-i}\\
&=\frac{R}{N\binom{N}{B}}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{R-1}\binom{R-1}{i}\binom{N-R}{B-1-i}\\
&\stackrel{V.I.}{=}\frac{R}{N\binom{N}{B}}\binom{N-1}{B-1}=\frac{RB}{N^2},
\end {array}
$$
where $V.I.$ means [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).